# Change the name of the dataset in the environment in R

Tags: r

I want to change the name of the dataset in the environment in R for example, I want to change the name (dataf44) here to (Final data)
how can I do that

[image]

Comment: Final_data <- dataf44 ; rm(dataf44)

Comment: If you really want the space (only really good if you are *programmatically documenting* actual object names in a report: `\`Final data\` <- dataf44` (and optionally `rm(dataf44)`). If it's just "you" working with this data, the code-golf (number of characters) to use `\`Final data\`` every time you want to do anything with the data can be annoying, over to you.

Answer (score 0):

`Final name` is not a good object name because of the space (although backticks could be used to work around this issue, but I don't recommend that). In general, just use assignment with `<-` and then remove the original object with `rm()`. For example,

```
new.object <- old.object
rm(old.object)
```